# How to add new items within an already published flutter app without updating it

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build an app in flutter that shows youtube videos from my channel and also some events I organize.
Every 3 days I organize a new event and I post a new youtube video. How can I always update my flutter app to show the latest events and videos without having to update it from magazin play or appstore?
I dont want my users to have to download it again and again with the newest code, I just want the elements to appear in the app.

Comment: You'll have to use a database for that..may be Firebase..just add all the details in database.. like event date.. details..video link etc..and code your app accordingly..so, whenever you do a new event..add it to Firebase..and..it will show to your users automatically..

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do it.

1. Use [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config). This allows you to 'push' the content from the server side to your app. As soon as user opens the app (and is online), the new settings are pushed. Moreover, you can also choose what content to push to which user e.g. spanish content for spanish speaking users and english contents for the rest etc. The possibilities are practically unlimited.

2A. Use Firestore (or like) database. Keep your data there which will be grabbed by the mobile app.

2B. Use non-Firestore like database e.g. MySQL, write REST APIs, let your mobile app call the APIs to get the contents and display it to the users.